# Деплой приложения react-create-app

Tags: reactjs, сервер, create-react-app

Есть ли возможность, что бы мой html после npm run build автоматом заливался на мой удалённый сервер?

Если есть, то как это реализуется?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48431170/how-to-deploy-a-create-react-app-to-a-web-host-ex-siteground

Answer (score 3):

Рекомендую настроить нормальный деплоймент процесс с использованием любого [CI/CD](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9D%D0%B5%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%8B%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F) сервиса. Например:

- [TravisCI](https://travis-ci.com/)
- [CircleCI](https://circleci.com/)

Если же такой вариант не подходит, то нужно смотреть какой у Вас "удаленный сервер", как Вы к нему подключаетесь, потом написать консольную команду для этого и поместить в **scripts** в *package.json*:

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test --env=jsdom",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject",
    "deploy": "npm run build && КОМАНДА ДЛЯ КОПИРОВАНИЯ ФАЙЛОВ НА ХОСТИНГ"
},
```

и запускать её как `npm run deploy`